# Como faço para o método Alert() no JS aparecer somente 1 vez quando o usuário logar na aplicação?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

A ideia é o seguinte, quando o usuário entrar na aplicação aparecerá para ele as mensagens cadastradas no banco, mas quero que apareça somente 1 vez para ele. E quando ele clicar para fechar a caixa de texto do Alert(), quero que faça um INSERT no banco passando o usuario, data e hora da visualização. Preciso de ajuda !!

### * Script.js* - Verifica se tem mensagens e retorna via AJAX

```
$('#form-msg').ready(function(){


    var form = $('#form-msg');
    var callback = form.find('input[name="callback"]').val();
    var callback_action = form.find('input[name="callback_action"]').val();
    var usuario = form.find('input[name="message_responsible"]').val();
    var type = form.find('input[name="message_type"]').val();
    //console.log(type);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'themes/intranet_fametro/ajax/' + callback + '.ajax.php',
        data: {
            'callback': callback,
            'callback_action': callback_action,
            'message_responsible': usuario,
            'message_type': type
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var obj = eval(data);
            obj.forEach(function(e){
                alert('Mensagem: ' + e.message_message);
            });
        }                     
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reescreva o método, guardando os erros em um array, para exibir todos uma única vez.

```
    success: function(data){
      const message = [];
      var obj = eval(data);
      obj.forEach(function(e){
        message.push(e.message_message);
      });

      alert('Mensagem: ' message.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! me ajudou muito

Answer (score 0):

> A caixa de diálogo de aviso deve ser utilizada para mensagens que não
>   requeiram nenhuma resposta da parte do usuário, a não ser o
>   reconhecimento da mensagem.
>   [fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Um recurso que você poderia utilizar para substituir o **alert** é com **confirm**, o único problema é que o usuário terá a opção de cancelar, mas com o confirm é possível receber a resposta do usuário:

```
const response = confirm('Mensagem: ' + e.message_message);
```

com a resposta você pode trabalhar em uma nova chamada ajax para seu backend e assim realizar o insert em seu banco de dados.

Comment: Bacana, obrigado pela dica, ajudou bastante clareando as ideias !

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a pergunta do título e considerando a explicação, entendi que essas mensagens são visualizadas somente uma vez, então:
Crie uma requisição Ajax ao seu backend, verificando se o registro da visualização das mensagens já foi inserido e, caso não tenha sido inserido, você faz uma nova requisição para carregar as mensagens e então as exibe como você já tem pronto.

Em questão a utilização do alert ,creio que não seja o que está buscando, pois não se pode controlar quando realmente foi fechada a janela. Como já dito em comentário anterior, o certo seria a utilização do confirm().

Segue documentação com exemplos de uso:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: Massa, vou tentar isso ! Obrigado